# Strange Margin/Padding on the bottom under footer in IE and CHROME, Firefox is fine CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have a responsive layout.

There is a footer:

```
margin-top: 3.39%;
width: 100%;
height: 6.668%;
min-height: 72px;
max-height: 96px;
background: #0073b5;
clear: both;
```

For some reason there is a white padding or margin under the footer, and for the past few hours I was struggling to figure out what causing it.

It only happens in Chrome and IE, Firefox is fine...

One way I managed to get the white space moving is by playing with height and margin-top combination, but cant find the right combination to get rid of whitespace while maintaining the same proportions on rest of layout

Please help!

Comment: I rolled back your edit, don't add sales links to your questions

Comment: @LGSon I've deleted link all along, site is in NDA and since urls shorteners to hide link from crawlers no longer allowed, had to post direct link. Now there is no need for it and it can't stay on question. Keep up the good spam-patrol work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `overflow: hidden;` on the footer seems to fix the issue.